# SQL server agent (SQLEXPRESS) unable to start service

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

Could not start service for server agent, tried as local service, 
Checked TCP-IP port and it is enabled,

I got connection refused while at `net.sorceforge.jtds.jdbc.connection`, the project is working on other environment,

Driver manager could not establish connection because of the service is unable start, any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: So you checked Windows services, and you're saying that the SQL Server Agent is not started?

Comment: Yes, checked services, Running sql on local system, no domain, no network, just workgroup, SQL Server service is running, I doubt is it a SQL agent which is not ruining causing the prob,